# aSmack 4.0.* XMPPTCPConnection can't connect to OpenFire and Ejabbered (SmackException$NoResponseException)

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am using **asmack-android-8-source-4.0.6**

when i try to connect to the server whether it is openFire or Ejabbered i get this exception

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException

here's my code:

```
        SmackAndroid.init(getApplicationContext());
        ConnectionConfiguration conConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
        conConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conConfig);
        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("AppName", "CONNECTED TO " + connection.getHost());
        }
```

when i call

> connection.connect();

i get this exception :

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException

note the i have tried the same code on **asmack-android-19-0.8.10** and it works perfectly

i guess the issue is with the

> XMPPTCPConnection

because in the **asmack-android-19-0.8.10** i use

> XMPPConnection

any help ?

Comment: Always post the full stacktrace of exceptions. Also set SmackConfiguration.DEBUG to true and show us the output.

Comment: @Flow i posted the answer below found here : https://community.igniterealtime.org/message/240285#240285

Comment: @Flow Thanks for your many helps !!! :) 
i have read many of your posts and comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem all i did is adding this line:

```
ConnectionConfiguration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
```

and i was connected to server successfully

here's my configuration in the end :

```
ConnectionConfiguration ConnectionConfiguration =  new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
ConnectionConfiguration.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
ConnectionConfiguration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I disabled security mode also and 
I am using this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36CSHhtnaEVDUrgqnWMzqW7) to connect to xmpp and i am getting [exception](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ), can you tell any solution for this?

Comment: what is the exception your getting ?

Comment: @user987760 have you worked on file sharing using xmpp and asmack. If yes, then kindly help in solving this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271210/4358880)

Comment: @AndroidRockss i did not user the xmpp file sharing, instead i'm using http for uploading/downloading Media and i send the urls through custom PackageExtention

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void connect() 
{

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SmackAndroid.init(getApplicationContext());

            ConnectionConfiguration conConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT);
            conConfig.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
            conConfig.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conConfig);
            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login("unm", "pswd");
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
                setConnection(connection);

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: could you please explain more about your answer? its not clear enough to understand

Comment: my code is about connection and login using asmack-android-8-4.0.6 library.